# How to set file name to NSData before uploading to server

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am currently making an app which converts an `NSDictionary` into a `JSON` file, in the intention of uploading it to a server. My issue is, is that I have no idea (let alone control) over what the name of the uploaded file is, how do I change/modify it?

Cheers,
Seb OH

Comment: Are you just asking about how to turn an NSString into NSData?

Comment: No @LyndseyScott, i'm trying to assign a file name to NSData, so when it's uploaded to the server it has a legitimate name.

Comment: You "suggest" the file name in the HTTP header.

Comment: What server side service are you using? Where are you trying to upload the JSON file?

Comment: @HotLicks, where do I access the HTTP header?? My own private FTP is the location for upload.

Comment: Without any code, this question won't get enough attention.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that should be handled by whatever FTP client library you are using.

For instance, FTPManager on GitHub (https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager) has the following method:

```
- (BOOL) uploadData:(NSData*)data withFileName:(NSString *)fileName toServer:(FMServer*)server;
```

That looks like it will fit your need just fine.